# how to replace every n-th value of an array in python most efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy

I was wondering whether there is a more pythonic (and efficient) way of doing the following:

```
MAX_SIZE = 100
nbr_elements = 10000
y = np.random.randint(1, MAX_SIZE, nbr_elements)


REPLACE_EVERY_Nth = 100
REPLACE_WITH = 120
c = 0

for index, item in enumerate(y):
    c += 1
    if (c % REPLACE_EVERY_Nth == 0):
        y[index] = REPLACE_WITH
```

So basically I generate a bunch of numbers from 1 to `MAX_SIZE-1`, and then I want to replace every `REPLACE_EVERY_Nth` element with `REPLACE_WITH`. This works fine but I guess it could be somehow done without using `enumerate`?

I was thinking something like this (which I know is wrong, because I replace the original y with the indices of y):

```
y = map(lambda x: REPLACE_WITH if not x%REPLACE_EVERY_Nth else x, range(len(y)))
```

is there a way to do modulo on the indices but replace the values?

Comment: Can't you just start with 1 and count by 100 (or N)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use a slicing with `REPLACE_EVERY_Nth` as step value:

```
y[::REPLACE_EVERY_Nth] = REPLACE_WITH
```

This is slightly different from your code, since it will start with the very first item (i.e. index 0).  To get exactly what your code does, use

```
y[REPLACE_EVERY_Nth - 1::REPLACE_EVERY_Nth] = REPLACE_WITH
```

Comment: This is wrong, `y[::REPLACE_EVERY_Nth]` create a list composed of every `Nth` item of `y`. You can't assign anything to it.

Comment: @Zenon: You can.  Try it.  And please take back the downvote.

Comment: @SvenMarnach great! how would you use an offset with that? i.e., every 5th element, but starting from element 13 on.

Comment: @Sven Marnach, I tried before downvoting: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: must assign iterable to extended slice` with python 2.7.

Comment: @Zenon: You used a list, not a NumPy array.  And even for a list, such an assignment is possible, but you need to assign, well, an iterable.

Comment: @Sven Marnach, it works with numpy arrays but not lists, I am really sorry, this is really cool!

Comment: @memyself: I included how to use an offset.

Comment: @Zenon, yes, it is really cool, isn't it! It stays cool even after the novelty wears off. Ahhh, numpy.

Comment: @Zenon: With lists, try something like: `y[::REPLACE_EVERY_Nth] = itertools.repeat(REPLACE_WITH, nbr_elements//REPLACE_EVERY_Nth)`

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use **range(start, end, step)** for your loop:

```
for index in range(0,len(y),REPLACE_EVERY_Nth):
    y[index] = REPLACE_WITH
```

Answer (score 1):

I think following solution can be applied without having any issues:

```
for index in xrange(0, len(y), REPLACE_EVERY_Nth):
    y[index] = REPLACE_WITH
```